# Simple Java Tic-Tac-Toe game

Tags: java, game, tic-tac-toe

About 2 weeks ago I made a Java game of Tic-Tac-Toe. It turned out great and it worked but it needed lots of help before it became a decent program. Since then, I have worked out lots of the kinks and errors. I would love to know what you think of my improved program.

```
public class ADitionalPractice {

public static boolean detection(boolean iswinning, char[][] board) {

    if (("" + board[0][0] + board[1][0] + board[2][0]).equals("xxx")) {
        iswinning = true;
    } else if (("" + board[1][0] + board[1][1] + board[2][1]).equals("xxx")) {
        iswinning = true;
    } else if (("" + board[0][2] + board[1][2] + board[2][2]).equals("xxx")) {
        iswinning = true;
    } else if (("" + board[0][0] + board[1][1] + board[2][2]).equals("xxx")) {
        iswinning = true;
    } else if (("" + board[2][0] + board[1][1] + board[0][2]).equals("xxx")) {
        iswinning = true;
    } else if (("" + board[0][0] + board[0][1] + board[0][2]).equals("xxx")) {
        iswinning = true;
    } else if (("" + board[1][0] + board[1][1] + board[1][2]).equals("xxx")) {
        iswinning = true;
    } else if (("" + board[2][0] + board[2][1] + board[2][2]).equals("xxx")) {
        iswinning = true;
    }
    return iswinning;
}
public static boolean detection1(boolean iswinning1, char[][] board) {

    if (("" + board[0][0] + board[1][0] + board[2][0]).equals("ooo")) {
        iswinning1 = true;
    } else if (("" + board[1][0] + board[1][1] + board[2][1]).equals("ooo")) {
        iswinning1 = true;
    } else if (("" + board[0][2] + board[1][2] + board[2][2]).equals("ooo")) {
        iswinning1 = true;
    } else if (("" + board[0][0] + board[1][1] + board[2][2]).equals("ooo")) {
        iswinning1 = true;
    } else if (("" + board[2][0] + board[1][1] + board[0][2]).equals("ooo")) {
        iswinning1 = true;
    } else if (("" + board[0][0] + board[0][1] + board[0][2]).equals("ooo")) {
        iswinning1 = true;
    } else if (("" + board[1][0] + board[1][1] + board[1][2]).equals("ooo")) {
        iswinning1 = true;
    } else if (("" + board[2][0] + board[2][1] + board[2][2]).equals("ooo")) {
        iswinning1 = true;
    }
    return iswinning1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    char board[][] = new char[3][3];
    int turn = 1;
    int y = 0;
    boolean validinput;
    boolean iswinning = false;
    boolean iswinning1 = false;

    while (true) {
        if (turn == 1) {
            System.out.println("player 1 it is your turn. your spot you wou"
                    + "ld like to enter.\n Ex: top,botton,middle left,right,middle");
            String input = keyboard.nextLine();

            validinput = true;
            if (input.equals("top left") && board[0][0] == '\u0000') {
                board[0][0] = 'x';
            } else if (input.equals("top middle") && board[1][0] == '\u0000') {
                board[1][0] = 'x';
            } else if (input.equals("top right") && board[2][0] == '\u0000') {
                board[2][0] = 'x';
            } else if (input.equals("middle left") && board[0][1] == '\u0000') {
                board[0][1] = 'x';
            } else if (input.equals("middle middle") && board[1][1] == '\u0000') {
                board[1][1] = 'x';
            } else if (input.equals("middle right") && board[2][1] == '\u0000') {
                board[2][1] = 'x';
            } else if (input.equals("bottom left") && board[0][2] == '\u0000') {
                board[0][2] = 'x';
            } else if (input.equals("bottom middle") && board[1][2] == '\u0000') {
                board[1][2] = 'x';
            } else if (input.equals("bottom right") && board[2][2] == '\u0000') {
                board[2][2] = 'x';
            } else {
                System.out.println("You have entered an invalid space "
                        + "please try again.");
                validinput = false;
            }
            if (validinput == true) {
                y++;
                turn++;
            }
            System.out.printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", board[0][0], board[1][0], board[2][0]);
            System.out.printf("____________\n");
            System.out.printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", board[0][1], board[1][1], board[2][1]);
            System.out.printf("____________\n");
            System.out.printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", board[0][2], board[1][2], board[2][2]);

           iswinning=detection(iswinning, board); 
            if (iswinning == true) {
                System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            if (y == 9) {
                System.out.println("the game ends in a draw.");
                System.exit(1);
            }

        }
        if (turn == 2) {
            System.out.println("player 2 it is your turn. your spot you"
                    + " would like to enter.\n Ex: top,botton,middle left,right,middle");
            String input = keyboard.nextLine();

            validinput = true;
            if (input.equals("top left") && board[0][0] == '\u0000') {
                board[0][0] = 'o';
            } else if (input.equals("top middle") && board[1][0] == '\u0000') {
                board[1][0] = 'o';
            } else if (input.equals("top right") && board[2][0] == '\u0000') {
                board[2][0] = 'o';
            } else if (input.equals("middle left") && board[0][1] == '\u0000') {
                board[0][1] = 'o';
            } else if (input.equals("middle middle") && board[1][1] == '\u0000') {
                board[1][1] = 'o';
            } else if (input.equals("middle right") && board[2][1] == '\u0000') {
                board[2][1] = 'o';
            } else if (input.equals("bottom left") && board[0][2] == '\u0000') {
                board[0][2] = 'o';
            } else if (input.equals("bottom middle") && board[1][2] == '\u0000') {
                board[1][2] = 'o';
            } else if (input.equals("bottom right") && board[2][2] == '\u0000') {
                board[2][2] = 'o';
            } else {
                System.out.println("You have entered an invalid space "
                        + "please try again.");
                validinput = false;
            }
            if (validinput) {
                turn--;
                y++;
            }
            System.out.printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", board[0][0], board[1][0], board[2][0]);
            System.out.printf("____________\n");
            System.out.printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", board[0][1], board[1][1], board[2][1]);
            System.out.printf("____________\n");
            System.out.printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", board[0][2], board[1][2], board[2][2]);
            iswinning1=detection(iswinning1, board); 
            if (iswinning1 == true) {
                System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
                System.exit(1);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some changes you want to make are:

- Encapsulate state into classes.
- Avoid using strings for logic.
- Avoid long functions
- Don't repeat yourself.

The aim would be to get your `main()` looking more like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Board = new Board();

    // I'm abusing the location state to double as the
    // current user, which is a bit hacky.
    BoardLocationState turn = BoardLocationState.FILLED_X;

    while (true) {

            BoardLocation location = null;

            //Repeat until we're given a valid location
            while(location==null) {
               printPrompt(turn);
               String input = keyboard.nextLine();
               location = locationMap.get(input);
               if(board.getState(location)!=BoardLocationState.EMPTY) {
                  location=null;
               }
            }
            board.setState(location, turn);
            board.printToStream(System.out);
            if(board.isWonBy(turn)) {
               printWinningMessage(turn);
               break;
            }
            if(board.isDraw()) {
               printDrawMessage(turn);
               break;
            }

            turn = nextTurn(turn);

        }

    }
```

A first pass at cleaning some of this up gets you something like this (very incomplete for now). See further down for what I'd be aiming to make your

```
public static class BoardLocation {
  public final int i;
  public final int j;
}

public static class Board {
  public enum BoardLocationState {
    FILLED_X,
    FILLED_O,
    EMPTY
  }

  // The combinations we need to check for winning or losing
  private final BoardLocation[][] rowsColumnsAndDiagonals = {
    { BoardLocation(0,0), BoardLocation(0,1), BoardLocation(0,2) },
    { BoardLocation(1,0), BoardLocation(1,1), BoardLocation(1,2) },
    { BoardLocation(2,0), BoardLocation(2,1), BoardLocation(2,2) },
    { BoardLocation(0,0), BoardLocation(1,0), BoardLocation(2,0) },
    { BoardLocation(1,0), BoardLocation(1,1), BoardLocation(2,1) },
    { BoardLocation(2,0), BoardLocation(1,2), BoardLocation(2,2) },
    { BoardLocation(0,0), BoardLocation(1,1), BoardLocation(2,2) },
    { BoardLocation(0,2), BoardLocation(1,1), BoardLocation(2,0) },
  };

  private final BoardLocationState[] state = new BoardLocationState[3*3];

  public Board() {
    for(int i=0; i<3*3; ++i) {
       state[i] = BoardLocationState.EMPTY;
    }
  }

  public BoardLocationState getState(BoardLocation location) {
    return state[location.i + location.j*3];
  }

  public void setState(BoardLocation location, BoardLocatioState newState) {
    state[location.i + location.j*3] = newState;
  }

  public boolean isWonBy(BoardLocationState user) {
    if(user==BoardLocationState.EMPTY)
       throw new RuntimeException("isWonBy should not be called with EMPTY");
    for(BoardLocation[] locations : rowsColumnsAndDiagonals) {
      if(checkRowColumnOrDiagonal(locations, user))
        return true;   
    }
    return false;
  }

  private boolean checkRowColumnOrDiagonal(BoardLocation[] locations, BoardLocationState user) {
    for(BoardLocation location : locations) {
       if(getState(location)!=user)
         return false;
    }
    return true;
  }



}
```

Comment: `rowsColumnsAndDiagonals = { { BoardLocation(0,0), BoardLocation(0,1)..` I think it will be better to replace for(0..2) for(0..2) and to define 2 as const, as scale-able solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider other computation algorithm:

```
O- give wage 10
x- give wage 100
```

to determine who wins you must sum each row and check:

```
if one of them is 30 - O wins
if one of them is 300 - X wins
if none - no one wins :)
```